# EJS Conditional import not showing html

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to display html only when variable user is defined, after login, but wherever I do, the include does not work

After login, user is redirected to '/' with object user populated

Console.log prints user when '/' route is called for second time

I have tryied different syntax, besides the one below:

```
if (user)...
if (typeof user !== "undefined")...
```

index.ejs:

```
<% var user; %>

<%- include('partials/head'); %>

<body>
  <%- include('partials/navbar'); %>

  <% if (user.length > 0) { %>


    <%- include('home'); %>

  <% }; %>


  <%- include('partials/scripts'); %>
</body>

<%- include('partials/footer'); %>
```

route:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {


  let user = req.cookies['user'];

  if(user){
    console.log(user);
  }

  res.render('index', user);

});

module.exports = router;
```

Part of login method (works, is sending populated object to route):

```
if (result == true) {

       let token = jwt.sign({ user: newUser }, 'secretkey', { expiresIn: '60s' });

            currentUser.jwt = token;
            currentUser.logado = true;
            res.cookie('user', currentUser);

            res.redirect('/');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call

```
res.render('index', user);
```

you are saying "use the properties of the value in `user` as variables in the EJS template." If your `user` value looked like `{ name: "foobar", isAdmin: false }`, then you'd effectively be doing

```
res.render('index', { name: "foobar", isAdmin: false });
```

Note that this would not create a template variable called `user`, beucase the object passed into `render` does not have a `user` property. Instead, you probably want to pass in an object which contains a property called `user` whose value is your `user` value:

```
res.render('index', { user: user });
```

Or equivalently and shorter:

```
res.render('index', { user });
```

Also, I'm unsure if `var user;` will shadow your `render`-supplied `user` value. I would recommend eliminating that statement from your EJS template.

Comment: it only works if I declare the variable at the top, can it be because I'm sending it to other partial?

Comment: @tramada I'm sorry to say I don't know much about EJS. You might try asking another question about that specifically, or, if you have something that runs correctly, just use what works.